# How to run a function when mouse enters a div, and vice versa?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I am trying to run a function when mouse hovers over the div, and when it leaves the div, it runs another function.

I have already tried using the `.hover();` function, which doesn't work.

```
<div id="test">
</div>

$("#test").hover(function() {
  window.alert("it worked!")
})
```

I am quite new to jQuery, I started about last month. Thanks!

Comment: Did you not read the documentation? https://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: using alert() to debug is a bad idea, use console.log.

Comment: just a test code I was going to change later...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`hover()`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/)

> Bind two handlers to the matched elements, to be executed when the mouse pointer enters and leaves the elements.

Precisely the first for `mouseenter` and the second for `mouseleave`.

**Working Code Example:**

```js
$("#test").hover(function() {
  console.log("Entered!")
}, function() {
  console.log("left!")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">Test
</div>
```

Comment: This is the most precise answer. `hover` can have two functions: first for `mouseover`, second for `mouseout` respectively.

Comment: This looks like it works fine, but would this in some way be not practical?  would it not work in certain situations?

Comment: @Recoding, well, I am not sure about those situations...may be you can share something....thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To run a function when your mouse enters, and when you mouse leaves is quite simple. you just use the `.mouseenter()` and `.mouseleave()` functions.

so in your context:

```
<div id="test">
</div>

$("#test").mouseenter(function() {
  window.alert("it worked");
})

$("#test").mouseleave(function() {
  window.alert("it worked");
})
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be OK, just pay attention to use the id attributes between "" and notice that alerts stops the browser of working until you interact with it.

Try this to see the mouse in and out in action:

```
$("#test").hover(function() {
  $("body").css('background-color','green');
}).mouseout(
function() {
  $("body").css('background-color','red');
});
```